# Problem with creating a scaffold within a voyager screen

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Im trying to create a screen that will have a topbar but i run in to a problem with the modifier, i got it to work with the normal included jetpack compose navigation but i cant seem to get it to work with the voyager library with uses override functions.
I need to include the parameter modifier: Modifier but get the error "Content overrides nothing"

```
package com.example.myapplication.ui.theme

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.CenterAlignedTopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import cafe.adriel.voyager.core.screen.Screen
import cafe.adriel.voyager.navigator.LocalNavigator



class Settings(modifier: Modifier): Screen {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @Composable
    override fun Content(modifier: Modifier) {
        val navigator = LocalNavigator.current

        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                    title = {
                    Text(text = "Settings") })
            }
        ) { contentPadding ->
            Column(modifier.padding(contentPadding)){

            }



        }
    }
```